# API codes from my Tezos node

Tags: api

I want to understand how I can extract the API codes from my working node to create a dashboard on my site.
I am interested in such parameters as: 
[bakingAll]
[bakingMiss]
[bakingSteal]
[endorsementAll]
[endorsementMiss]
As well as the block numbers at the beginning and end of the cycle. And all that is connected with the balance of the delegate

Comment: Have you looked at the RPC documentation?

Comment: https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/rpc.html#rpcs-full-description

Comment: You could also consider using an indexer instead of your node, as depending on the mode (full vs archive) you are running it, you may only get data for the past 5 cycles.